# PHP Eval Math Function for Bot

Tags: php, math, eval, bots

I am working on a math function for an IRC bot, however I can't seem to get this to work for powers of numbers, i.e 5**2, The goal is to keep it as safe as possible since it does use eval, and to be able to do a lot of general math in addition to that.
Right now, this is what I have. Is there possibly a better / more efficient way?
Thanks in advance.

```
 case ':$math':
              $input = rtrim($this->get_message()); // grabbing the user input
              $input = preg_replace('/[0-9+*%.\/-(\*\*)]/', '', $input);
              $sum = $this->do_math($input); // store the return of our input passed through the do_math function into $sum
              if($sum == "NULL") {
                  break;
              }
              else {
                  $this->send_message("The value is: ".$sum); // echo the value
              }
              break;





  function do_math($input) {
        $result=eval("return ($input);"); // using eval to preform math on the specified input
        if($result == NULL) {
            $this->send_message("Invalid characters were assigned in the math function!");
            return "NULL";
            break;
        }
        else {
            return $result; // return the sum
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is not ** operator in php ... you should use the pow function instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comment there is no ** operator in php, the pow function should be used instead ... what you can do to emulate it though is to throw another preg_replace at the input.

```
$input = rtrim($this->get_message()); // grabbing the user input
$input = preg_replace('/([0-9.]+)\*\*([0-9.]+)/', 'pow($1, $2)', $input);
$sum = $this->do_math($input);
```

Comment: For this to work, I had to remove the first preg_replace. Thanks for the fast reply!